# How to avoid too many != null checks

Tags: c#

throught my app I've seen too many not equal null checks, which looks like this:

```
if (receivedRequest != null && receivedRequest.Status != null)
```

Is there cleaner way to write things like this?

Comment: In this case "if (receivedRequest?.Status != null)" would be equivalent to the example you gave (only possible since c# 6)

Comment: AKA: [the null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-).

Comment: You might consider using [code contracts](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/1172/code-contracts-csharp-static-runtime-checks).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, since C# 6 you can use [null propagation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator/)... something like this:

```
if (receivedRequest?.Status != null)
```

Check out this [blog post](https://davefancher.com/2014/08/14/c-6-0-null-propagation-operator/) with additional details...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create un check method:

```
private bool CheckReceivedRequest()
{
  return receivedRequest != null && receivedRequest.Status != null;
}
```

Used like that:

```
if ( CheckReceivedRequest() ) 
{ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If receivedRequest.Status is not null, you don't need to check if receivedRequest is null.

```
if (receivedRequest.Status != null)
```